# Store message on memory instead of JVM- ActiveMQ

Tags: java, php, out-of-memory, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm working on ActiveMQ where the producer is in PHP and consumer is in JAVA. I'm using STOMP to connect PHP to AMQ.
A total of 10,000 messages are sent.
Consider a case where the JAVA subscriber is down, i.e. there are no consumer available to consume the message.
When trying this case on my local system, After 3000 messages, ActiveMQ throws a Java.MemoryOutOfBound Exception.

So I'm thinking of few of the solutions :
1. Is there any way by which ActiveMQ can store the messages on the KahaDB instead of in-memory?
2. Are any system tweaks that i can try (Already tried increasing the Java Heap size to 3GB, I was able to send 9000 messages but after that same error), Any ActiveMQ options that can be enabled or disabled that can help.
3. Any better solution than the ones that I've thought of?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ActiveMQ docs, you can switch your broker to persisting using KahaDB buy configuring

```
<broker brokerName="broker" ... >
 <persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="activemq-data" journalMaxFileLength="32mb"/>
 </persistenceAdapter>
 ...
</broker>
```

There are many options that you could apply to tweak according to your scenario, take a look at

http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html

Comment: Tried with this already... Used options such as -maxAsyncJobs, increased indexCacheSize...But still facing the issue...